# Which meaning added by "what have you" in the sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> Well,at work i tend to read for information and what have you,so i'd say that with TV it probably just help me relax and unwind.

Maybe with  removing the "and what have you" ,the sentence is still clear.
Which meaning added by "what have you"?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what) defines it as "whatnot".

Answer (score 1):

It means "and things like that" in this context. (In its original sense, it was "and I don't know what else".)

That puts it in a family with these phrases:

> and so on
> and whatnot
> etc etc
> and the like
> and such

The force of the phrase is that any other reasons for reading at work are similar to or even grouped under the heading "for information".